# BootstrapVue's b-nav with lazy loading

Tags: typescript, vue.js, tabs, lazy-loading, bootstrap-vue

I can't wrap my head around the following problem:

I have a Vue.js component in which I need tabs with routes. I went for a variant of [b-nav Tabs style (official docs)](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/nav#card-integration) and it is working fine, regarding the tabs and routing.
The problem: I can't figure out **how to lazy load the tab-content** of each `item` in `myItems` instead of loading them all on requesting one of the tab routes.

The routes look like this: `localhost/items/#tab0`, `localhost/elements/#tab1` etc.

(Btw: b-tabs have built in lazy loading, but are not routable! Can't use them :-/)

This is the code of my component's template:

```
<template>
    <div class="tabs">
        <b-nav tabs>
            <b-nav-item
                v-for="(item, index) in myItems"
                :key="item.Id"
                :to="'#tab' + item.Id"
                :active="$route.hash === '#tab' + item.Id || (index === 0 && $route.hash === '')"
            >
                {{ item.name }}
            </b-nav-item>
        </b-nav>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div
                v-for="(item, index) in myItems"
                :key="item.Id"
                class="tab-pane"
                :class="{ active: $route.hash === '#tab' + item.Id || (index === 0 && $route.hash === '') }"
            >
                <!-- indidivual output here, depending on route | I want to lazy load this -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And this my TypeScript code:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { Vue, Component, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

    @Component()
    export default class MyItemsTabs extends Vue {
        @Prop() readonly myItems!: Item[] | null;
    }
</script>
```

EDIT:
Of, let's say 7 tabs, I need to lazy load only 2, the other's immeditately.

Anybody got an idea? Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

I created a component for the tab content:

Template:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <TabContent
    v-for="(item, index) in myItems"
    class="tab-pane"
    :class="{ active: $route.hash === '#tab' + item.Id || (index === 0 && $route.hash === '') }"
    :key="item.Id"
    :tab-content="item"
  />
</div>
```

In the new `TabContent` component, I check:

Template:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- no "pre-loading" -->
        <TabContent1
            :v-if="$route.hash === "#tab" + item.Id && item.name === 'tabName1'"
        />

        <!-- no "pre-loading" -->
        <TabContent2
            :v-if="$route.hash === "#tab" + item.Id && item.name === 'tabName2'"
        />

        <!-- loaded immediately -->
        <TabContentDefault v-else />
    </div>
</template>
```

This is simplified code, of course. In reality I use functions for the checks and way more properties.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here:

First, you can use `b-tab` and implement routing for them, using query params may help you. you need to use `@change` every time one tab changes.

Second, you can implement a component for showing your output:

```
<MyCustomComponent v-for="(item, index) in myItems" :key="item.id" :is="selected_component_name " />
```

check the [vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about the Dynamic Components, I'll check it out.

Comment: Humbly, I think you made a mistake: `:is` cannot take a boolean, it must be: "the name of a registered component, or a component’s options object". (it breaks the app, indeed)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes you are right, I'll edit my answer. @jasie